# rails_admin enum field it's not selecting the stored value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums, rails-admin

I'm having troubles with rails admin and a model with belongs_to association, I have included the enum statement to get the dropdownlist with the names and values and it is showing the list correctly but it's not showing the selected value that would be the stored for the activerecord.

```
field :action_type, :enum do
   label "Actions"
   enum do
      ActionType.all.collect {|p| [p.name, p.id]}
   end
end
```

Comment: did you define `enum` in model?

Comment: just define this in `rails_admin` section `field  :action_type do
     help 'Select Option.'
    end`

Comment: I didn't define the enum on the model I just did it directly on the field

Comment: Ok I have found the error it was the field attribute name, should be :action_type_id no :action_type, action_type_id is the name of the column

Comment: Please define `enum` in your model then it will handle all stuff

Comment: which rails_admin and rails version are you using? @rome3ro